# Is it okay to store money as decimal(22,2) in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sqldatatypes

Is it okay to store money values as `decimal(22,2)` in MySQL? I am writing a web based marketplace and Ad network for a virtual world.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

What if someone has sextillion dollars?!? The field couldn't contain this massive pile of 
benjamins....

In seriousness though, SQL Server and PostgreSQL have a money datatype, and Access has a currency datatype. Oracle and MySQL have neither.

This thread - [Best data type for storing currency values in a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628637/best-data-type-for-currency)

however recommends 4 significant digits for some reason, I suppose in case you need fractional cents (stock shares, etc).

If no user could have over sextillion dollars (in seriousness), and you don't need to calculate fractions of cents for storage, your format should be just fine.

Comment: Yeah. i think this will work. I doubt anyone even has that much money in this game! But i do wish MySQL would add a money type.

Comment: Bear in mind that if the application may expand to take into account other currencies, you may very well need more than 2 digits for the precision.  Bitcoin, as the most extreme example I'm aware of, uses 8 digits precision.  And there are several others that use 3 digits.

Answer (score 6):

You should ask yourself "What is the most amount of money someone will have using my program?" and "To what precision do I require my decimal places?"

If you only need to handle up to a billion, then it seems (10,2) would be sufficient. If you wanted more precision for interest calculations perhaps you want (10,5). If you're just keeping track of a payroll and annual salary, it seems (7,2) would be sufficient (and I'd like to be in the 7 part, thanks!)

Without knowing the purpose of your data, it's hard to answer this. All I can give you is the questions you have to ask yourself.

Answer (score 2):

If you are storing money in a database, you can use the int type but store in the minimal value (cent for dollars), then just divide by 100 when needed. It will work faster.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer by @Orbit on this page mentions that SQL Server has a `money` data type.

However, according to this answer ([Should you choose the MONEY or DECIMAL(x,y) datatypes in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server)), a better choice for storing monetary values in SQL Server is `decimal(19,4)` - which is also available in MySQL.

From what I understand you should be careful when performing calculations with the `money` type in `SQL Server` due to floating point rounding errors. And it may use the `decimal(19,4)` type indirectly anyway.

So... the `decimal(22,2)` type would be fine to store monetary values... But as a lot of people seem to recommend, `decimal(19,4)` would be better.