# Accounting system - MySQL and PHP precision

Tags: php, mysql, currency, floating-accuracy, bcmath

I'm building a kind of accounting system with PHP and MySQL. My database has `DECIMAL (11,2)` columns for currency, and also `DECIMAL`for all other values used on operations with currency (like percentages to be applied). I've never programmed something like that before, so I am not sure I am doing the right thing.

**Am I using the correct level of precision at the database?**

On the PHP side:

**Should I use BC Math functions on any values that may be later stored on the database?**

I also have to format the money values with `,` as the decimal point, and `.` as the thousands separator. I know `number_format`, and recently discovered `money_format`, but the manual says both operate with floats.

**Can I use `number_format` or `money_format` for values that will be displayed, or exported to CSV or Excel?**

Comment: I could be wrong, but usually financial systems will use at least 3 fraction digits (`DECIMAL(10,3)`). PHP itself is not great with float numbers; the best would probably be to do x100 and use integers only, optionally using BC Math.

Comment: Just a quick note - it's usually not a best idea to use floats when working with money.

Comment: @pyrate I know, that's why I asked the question.

Comment: Here is similar question [answered][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628637/best-data-type-for-currency

Answer (score 0):

you can use number_format() to display or export the content as csv/excel. But keep in mind while exporting as csv/excel using number_format() with decimal separator as comma(,) you have to use double quotes(").
`Just like "2,22.00".`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that. Anyway I think I'm going to export the values in US formats, and localized copies of Excel should detect automatically, and display the values in the correct format for the current locale.