# Size for my Double type

Tags: mysql

Hy,

I want that one of my  columns in my product table stands for totalPrice. Which size of double type is recommended?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628637/best-data-type-for-currency

Comment: It depends on your application , so analyze your application and decide size. you can use 'DECIMAL' datatype.

Answer (score 3):

You shoud use a fixed point type for that like:

```
numeric(10,2)
```

> These types are used when it is important to preserve exact precision, for example with monetary data.

See [MySQL Doc](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fixed-point-types.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can use any data type values of your choice in `DECIMAL` datatype of MySQL e.g.

```
DECIMAL(19,4)
```

As suggested by @stb [Best data type for storing currency values in a MySQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628637/best-data-type-for-currency)