# Stripe Currency - Are all amounts in cents / 100ths, or does it depend on currency?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am currently writing the code to migrate to Stripe from a different payment processor.

I know that when the currency is USD, stripe uses cents.  So stripe(1000 USD) == $10.00.  Same for Euros I assume stripe(1000 EUR) == € 10.00.

But what about JPY?  100 JPY is roughly $1.  So do I send Stripe 10000 JPY to get 100 Yen ~= $1.  Do I send Stripe 100 JPY to get 100 Yen ~= $1?

Is there a special divisor?  Is everything denominated in 100/ths for any currency?  I can't find an answer in the documentation, and I don't want to charge Japanese people $0.1 or $1000 for a $10 USD service.

How is AED denominated.  They use 1/10ths as the smallest unit / coinage.  Should I multiply by 10?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

All amounts are in the "smallest common currency unit". While in most places this would be cents, in Japan there is no decimal for their currency so amount=1 (1 JPY), since ¥1 is the smallest currency unit.

Additional info can be found at [this doc](https://support.stripe.com/questions/which-zero-decimal-currencies-does-stripe-support).

Comment: Thanks.  I wish they had real docs, not dated support questions.  I updated my question to ask about AED (UAE Dirhams, which are denominated in 1/10ths.)

Comment: i'll be dog gonnit. riiiiggghhhtt.... that `currency: 'usd'` field passed to Stripe certainly requires one to intuitively think, ..oh yea, they're expecting $10.21 to be represented as `1021`... overengineered. KISS principle violation here.

Comment: its generally recommended that you use cents when dealing with currencies. All the lower level banking apis assume this as well. Computers tend to be bad at adding decimals (since base 2 to base 10 decimals don't convert cleanly, in many languages `.1 + .2 != .3`)

Comment: @RonRoyston Well, actually not. This is the simplest way of handling currencies especially if you consider programming language disasters: https://hackernoon.com/js-wtf-with-math-79da9a941ec1