# Stripe getting amount different from expected while creating a plan through API

Tags: stripe-payments, .net-core-2.0

I am creating a plan in stripe through its API and I get the issue of amount.The problem is I am having a long datatype of Amount in c# (.net core 2.0 )When I pass 1600 as a value the Stripe takes on 16 as an amount and creates a plan of $ 16 whereas I want to create a plan of $1600. What can be the change I need to make for this .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stripe Currency - Are all amounts in cents / 100ths, or does it depend on currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326710/stripe-currency-are-all-amounts-in-cents-100ths-or-does-it-depend-on-curren)

Comment: Amounts in Stripe's API are always in cents, so `amount:1600` means 1600 cents i.e. $16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd like to create a plan for $1600 (US Dollars) You need to pass in `160000`. Stripe's API works based on [zero decimal currencies](https://stripe.com/docs/currencies#zero-decimal). Other currencies may not have cents (or the equivalent) i.e. Japanese Yen.