# Localizing Stripe Payment on Sylius

Tags: stripe-payments, sylius

I have added Stripe Payment Gateway on sylius project. It is working well but there is just one problem. By default, USD currency is used so it multiplied to 100 (7$ * 100 = 700 cents) when sent to the Stripe server. But in my case, I am using JPY so I do not need to multiply to 100.
I have checked the resources and found this on ConvertPaymentAction.php

```
    $this->gateway->execute($currency = new GetCurrency($payment->getCurrencyCode()));
    $divisor = pow(10, $currency->exp);

    $details = ArrayObject::ensureArrayObject($payment->getDetails());
    $details['amount'] = $payment->getTotalAmount() / $divisor
```

Is there a good way to solve this problem? I am new to Sylius so I am not sure how should I handle this. Should I override the Conversion Method or just make a new whole Entity for Stripe method.

Comment: This looks a bit like a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35326710/stripe-currency-are-all-amounts-in-cents-100ths-or-does-it-depend-on-curren?rq=1

Comment: @MigMolRod No, it is not duplicate. I am asking how to resolve the issue on Sylius not on Stripe

Comment: Which gateway factory are you using?