# What is the data type for Currency in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

What is the data type to the currency value in SQL Server.

e.g: I want to store `$11.23`.

Can I use money type and addtionally will it store the `$` symbol?

Comment: any `numeric` data type will not store any `symbol` if you put symbol you have to phase lot of problem to calculate that amount

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best data type for currency values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628637/best-data-type-for-currency-values)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should you choose the MONEY or DECIMAL(x,y) datatypes in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582797/should-you-choose-the-money-or-decimalx-y-datatypes-in-sql-server)

Comment: There's no point in using `money`, it doesn't store any currency info, has limited range and a hard-coded precision of 4. Typically a `decimal` with a specific range and precision is used, eg `decimal(9,2)` specifies 9 digits, 2 of which are decimals. `money` more for for compatibility with VB6 and OLEDB than anything else

Answer (score 4, accepted):

answering to the question in the title, the datatype for currency is `MONEY`.

the `money` datatype will store the information only, without the format: in your example the information is `11.23` so that's what is saved into the database.

the `$` sign is part of the format so it will not be stored into the `money` field.

the usual solution is to have a `MONEY` field for the amount and a `VARCHAR` field for the currency symbol/name.

Comment: `money` isn't useful as it *doesn't* store any currency info. It's simply a decimal type with less precision than a `decimal`. It also *doesn't* allow you to specify precision, eg when values are allowed to only have 2 decimals. What does `21.3455 $` mean?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that's your opinion, mine is different. if you need to change precision and scale then go with other datatypes but if `MONEY` (**knowing its specifications**) fits then can be a valid choice as any other datatype.

Comment: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_money

Answer (score 11):

```
DECLARE @Price Decimal(18,2) = 11.23
SELECT FORMAT(@Price,'c','en-US') AS 'CURRENCY IN US Culture'
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the best way to store the currency is to use either **NUMERIC** or **DECIMAL** data types as these values participates in calculations. If we use NVARCHAR to allow the storage with symbol like ($), it will cost extra during calculations when use in WHERE clause.
We can choose the **precision and scale** accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

it should be `DECIMAL(,)` OR `NUMERIC` in SQL.
eg `DECIMAL(20,2)`