# How to store integer data with comma in it?

Tags: mysql

I am having some difficulties about storing integer data with commas, I have prices, which is like 4,600 So I need to store it with commas but when I try to send it as Integer it cut after first number. I tried to change column type. `BigInt` or `Double` but it doesn't effect any. Any possible way to do that?

Also tried to change comma to dot "." but with this, mysql delete the "0" at last... I don't know why...

```
Prices
------
4,500
2,300
1,500
```

Comment: You can't. You should format on output if need be. You could store as varchar but then it wouldn't be an integer and you would have to convert every time you wished to use it in a calculation.

Comment: Do not store with comma, even you use it with number formatting function when ever you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using a comma, MySQL most likely interprets the number as two fields, separated by the comma. For example:

```
Prices,Unspecified
------,-----------
4     ,500
2     ,300
1     ,500
```

In the numbers in question: If the comma is a thousands separator, remove it (via String replace) before trying to store the number. If it's a decimal point, replace it with a period (via String replace) and store it as a `DOUBLE` (or `DECIMAL` if you need high accuracy for large numbers).

If you want to *display* the number with a comma, use String formatting (possibly a number-formatting function other than `String.format()` or `sprintf()`) after retrieving the value from the database.

Comment: in the end I stored the numbers without commas and add the commas after fetching the data... I actually don't know is it the best solution but,,, yea no other choice I guess,,,

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be able to do calculations using SQL queries with those numbers, then you need to store the price either use the [`DECIMAL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/precision-math-decimal-characteristics.html) type or use integer types and multiply the number by e.g. `1000` before saving.

Double or any other floating point representation of numbers are not suitable for price calculations/storage.

If you use `DECIMAL` need to convert the number form your local format `4,5000` to the format the database expects when you store it in the database, and convert it back to the local format when you retrieve your data.

If you store it as string then you can keep your local format but that's the worst solution, and should never be used.